# Where to override core.php for wp-pagenavi?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pagination

I'm using Wordpress plugin ***wp-pagenavi*** and I need to override the default "previous" and "next" link with images. I can do it when writing this in ***core.php*** of the plugin's files :

```
if ( $paged > 1 && !empty( $options['prev_text'] ) ) {

// Custom image
$previmage = '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_prev_01_pc.png" alt="前の記事へ" />';
$prev_text = '<span>'.$options['prev_text'].'</span>'.$previmage;

$out .= $instance->get_single( $paged - 1, $prev_text, array(
    'class' => $class_names['previouspostslink'],
    'rel'   => 'prev'
) );
}
```

The problem is that it's not reliable as it will be deleted as soon as I update the plugin. Is there a way to custom these links without javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a way to override this plugin, but a workaround would be to just write a custom pagination :

```
function wp_corenavi() {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $next = '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_next_01_pc.png"sizes="(max-width: 750px) 42px, 60px" srcset="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_next_01.png 85w,'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_next_01_pc.png 60w,'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_next_01_pc@2x.png 120w"alt="次の記事へ" />';
    $prev = '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_prev_01_pc.png"sizes="(max-width: 750px) 40px, 58px" srcset="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_prev_01.png 81w,'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_prev_01_pc.png 58w,'.get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/btn_prev_01_pc@2x.png 116w"alt="前の記事へ" />';

    $pages = '';
    $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if (!$current = get_query_var('paged')) $current = 1;
    $a['base'] = str_replace(999999999, '%#%', get_pagenum_link(999999999));
    $a['total'] = $max;
    $a['current'] = $current;

    $total = 1; //1 - display the text "Page N of N", 0 - not display
    $a['mid_size'] = 2; //how many links to show on the left and right of the current
    $a['end_size'] = 1; //how many links to show in the beginning and end
    $a['prev_text'] = $prev; //text of the "Previous page" link
    $a['next_text'] = $next; //text of the "Next page" link
    $a['before_page_number'] = '<span class="pagination_elem">';
    $a['after_page_number'] = '</span>';

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if ($max > 1) echo '<div id="js_pagination" class="wp-pagenavi">';
    echo $pages . paginate_links($a);
    if ($max > 1) echo '</div>';
}
```